# change div height after copying div

Tags: html

I copied a div col2 from index.html to my current div colabout2 first. Then, I want to change the height of the div colabout2 according to the div colabout1 in the same page. However, the following code doesn't work:

```
        '<div id="colabout2">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#colabout2').load('index.html #col2');
            </script>
        </div>
        <script>
            var h = $('#colabout1').height();
            $('#colabout2').height(h);
        </script>'
```

Please help. Thx.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?  Have you tried setting the height in the ajax callback?

Comment: First and foremost, your code is not valid.

Comment: sorry... I expect colabout2 to have the same height of colabout1 after the code executed, but colabout2 only has its original height which display all contents inside it and colabout2 ignores colabout1's height at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#colabout2').css("height", $('#colabout1').height());
```

### Explanation:

Use the `.css()` function to configure and objects CSS then get `colabout1`'s height and set it as the second parameter of the `.css()` function and set `"height"` as the first.

Comment: I used $('#colabout2').load('index.html #col2'); $('#colabout2').css("height",$('#colabout1').height()); but it won't help. After copying, colabout2 has a <ul> which is longer than the height of colabout1. Although colabout2 is a scroll list, it still display everything...

Comment: @user2559898 can u make a fiddle please? so that I can understand more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Use .css for changing style of the element. For example `$('#colabout').css('height',h);`